# Efficient way to split enum flags to create distinct items in collection

Tags: c#, .net, enums, split, flags

I have a collection like this:

```
IEnumerable<RecordToSend> recordsToSend;
```

Made up of the following:

```
public class RecordToSend {
    public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public ScheduleTypes Schedule { get; set; }
}
```

And flag enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum ScheduleTypes
{
    None = 0,
    Daily = 1,
    Weekly = 2,
    Monthly = 4
}
```

---

So let's say I have the following collection, which is basically pulled out of the database using an Entity Framework query:

```
| ApplicationId | Schedule |
| ABC123        | 7        |
| DEF456        | 3        |
```

What would be an effective way to split on the enum into multiple distinct records, resulting in this (could use the `RecordToSend` class, or another type, even a dynamic if it makes sense):

```
| ApplicationId | Schedule |
| ABC123        | 1        |
| ABC123        | 2        |
| ABC123        | 4        |
| DEF456        | 1        |
| DEF456        | 2        |
```

---

Note the `ScheduleTypes` enum has a 0 value flag, which I'd like to ignore in the result.

Efficiency is not of utmost concern, though I'm curious to hear thoughts on performance of different approaches. If it's possible to perform this split in a single step as part of the Entity Framework query as I'm pulling the collection out of the database, that would be great. Within the application I don't have any need for the enum flags in their original, multi-value state.

Answer (score 5):

This should work.

```
var results = records.SelectMany(
    r => Enum.GetValues(typeof(ScheduleTypes))
             .Cast<ScheduleTypes>()
             .Where(e => e != ScheduleTypes.None && r.Schedule.HasFlag(e))
             .Select(e => 
                 new RecordToSend
                 {
                     Guid = r.Guid, 
                     Schedule = e
                 }));
```

Basically for each record it loops through the possible enum values (skipping the 0 value) and checking if `Schedule` has that flag.  Then creates a new record with the same `Guid` and the enum flag.  The `SelectMany` then flattens the collection of records that was created.

Note that if `records` is an `IQueryable` you'll have to add a `AsEnumerable` as I doubt this will translate to SQL.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'll try this and report back. Basically exactly what I'm looking for it sounds like, and wasn't sure the high-level concept to dig into.

Comment: Thank  you again for the help! This did basically exactly what I needed. I did have to do some casting to make it actually work with my code (not sure if that's specific to my code or not) so I'd like to suggest the edits here and you may accept them if they make sense.

Comment: You are correct.  `Enum.GetValues` returns an `Array` and you'll need to cast the values.  I've fixed that by adding `Cast<ScheduleTypes>()` after it.

Answer (score -1):

Try linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<RecordToSend> recordsToSend = new List<RecordToSend>() {
                new RecordToSend() { ApplicationId = System.Guid.Parse("00000001-0001-0001-0001-000000000123"), Schedule = ScheduleTypes.Daily},
                new RecordToSend() { ApplicationId = System.Guid.Parse("00000001-0001-0001-0001-000000000123"), Schedule = ScheduleTypes.Weekly},
                new RecordToSend() { ApplicationId = System.Guid.Parse("00000001-0001-0001-0001-000000000123"), Schedule = ScheduleTypes.Monthly},
                new RecordToSend() { ApplicationId = System.Guid.Parse("00000001-0001-0001-0001-000000000456"), Schedule = ScheduleTypes.Daily},
                new RecordToSend() { ApplicationId = System.Guid.Parse("00000001-0001-0001-0001-000000000456"), Schedule = ScheduleTypes.Weekly}
            };

            var results = recordsToSend.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.ApplicationId)
                .Select(x => new {
                    ApplicationID = x.Key, 
                    Schedule = x.Select(y => (int)y.Schedule).Sum()
                 }).ToList();

        }
    }
    [Flags]
    public enum ScheduleTypes
    {
        None = 0,
        Daily = 1,
        Weekly = 2,
        Monthly = 4
    }
    public class RecordToSend
    {
        public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public ScheduleTypes Schedule { get; set; }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: This is combining, not separating.